# How to jump after while(1) via SIGHUP in Perl?

Tags: perl, loops, signals

I like to jump after the `while(1)`. How to do that? **Checking a special variable and `last` is not ok because the while expression contains an *blocking call* so it would be too late if the expression is checked.**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );
use sigtrap 'handler', \&hup_handler, 'HUP';
my $counter = 0;
sub hup_handler { say 'HUP!!!'; $counter = 0; return; }
say 'It starts here';
while ( 1 ) {
    sleep( 1 ); # Blocking call is in reality within while expression.
    say ++$counter;
}
say 'It ends here';
```

Comment: what do you mean with jump after while(1)? you mean breaking the loop? try break;

Comment: @Perroloco This is a Perl question. There is no `break` command (in the context of a loop) in Perl.

Comment: `last` and whatever ist **too late** because of the **blocking** call within the `while` expression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should be possible by throwing an exception, a.k.a. die(), inside your signal handler.

So try doing something like this:

```
say 'It starts here';
eval {
    local $SIG{HUP} = sub { say 'HUP!!!'; $counter = 0; die "*bang*"; }

    while ( 1 ) {
        sleep( 1 ); # Blocking call is in reality within while expression.
        say ++$counter;
    }
}
say 'It ends here';
```

Of course any of the module providing a more normal looking try/catch syntax would work.

Comment: It answers my question, thank you :) but if the `*bang*` occurres outside the eval my program dies :'(

Comment: You can move the signal handler inside the loop as I have changed the code to. I have never used the sigtrap pragma, so I am not sure if it works correctly lexically. Instead I have used %SIG directly.

Comment: I have checked the implementation of the sigtrap pragma and it looks like it only supports global signal handlers. So you need to use %SIG directly if you only want your handler used in a limited scope.